# Scheduled ftp task on server

Tags: windows-server-2003, ftp

I need to write a batch file that will run every day (Win server 2003) and will upload a sql-server backup file to a ftp account (backup)?

I have the host, username and password and the path to the folder that contains the file
the file name is new every day so I don't know it.

The folder contains just one file.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get the SQL job to create a fixed name file, we can rename it later.

**Step 1**
Machine A runs the SQL backup job, scheduled with a SQL job.

**Step 2**
Once the SQL backup has completed Machine A runs a scheduled task that executes FTP_upload.bat to upload the SQL .bak file to FTP service B.

**Contents of FTP_upload.bat**

```
ftp -s:ftptransfer.cfg
```

**Contents of ftptransfer.cfg**

```
Open <ipAddress of FTP service>
<username>
<password>
Binary
Put <full path and name of .bak file> <remote path at location>
quit
```

Modify the scheduled task times accordingly to fit with the backup and transfer times for your machines / file sizes

**Step 3**
Once the transfer has completed, create another scheduled task on Machine A to execute rename_backup.bat

**Contents of rename_backup.bat**

```
@echo off

FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2*" %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET DATE=%%B
SET DATE=%DATE:/=%
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%A IN ('TIME/T') DO SET TIME=%%A
SET TIME=%TIME::=%
set TODAY=%date%
echo %TODAY%"
rename ".\SQL.bak" "SQL_%today%.bak" 
@echo on
```